# Fragment tutorial causing java nullpointer exception

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

So I keep getting a null pointer error whenever anything is done by transaction.  I'm following the tutorial here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate using Android Studio.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_profile);
    // Find the user's profile picture custom view FACEBOOK
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();

}
```

So far the only place I've had to deviate from the tutorial is in the class definition.  It's set to `public class ManageProfileActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SelectionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, SplashFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {` instead of `public class ManageProfileActivity extends FragmentActivity`

The app will build and run fine with transaction.hide(fragments[i]); commented out, but then it just overlays the fragments on top of each other.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the NullPointerException?  Does it break on the first run through the for-loop?

Comment: Don't have a stacktrace (I'll work on getting one) it breaks on the first time through the loop.

Comment: I think I had issues with running the Facebook test apps.  I think I just tried creating my own login flow.  Throw in some null checks for the fragments[].  I feel like there might be a problem with the splashFragment/selectionFragment.  Make sure that you've imported the support library for the fragments.